# What is a HP StorageWorks MSA P2000 Default Credentials vulnerability

Tags: security, mcafee

What is a HP StorageWorks MSA P2000 Default Credentials vulnerability.I m getting this error message from Mcafee , can anybody help.

Answer (score 0):

Well...typing this EXACT PHRASE in to Google results in multiple descriptions of that is being alerted.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02660754

This device ships with a well-known admin password and it looks like you didn't change it to something else, so anyone that can communicate with this device can readily gain admin access to it.